# Juno boots to black screen with top menu visible

Tags: macbook

Hardware: White MacBook mid-2010, Intel Processor Duo Core, 8 GB RAM, SSD
Loki was successfully installed on this MacBook prior. When I installed Juno via the directions using Etcher and reboot there is screen flicker and what appears to be almost a boot loop or video problems. The dock is visible for a split second and then the screen is dark except for the notification menu (Bluetooth, start button, volume.)  I assume this is a video driver issue?! Open to suggestions...Loki is successfully re-installed. The funny thing is I am having problems with most recent Linux distros: Ubuntu 18 does not finish install, etc.  Open to any suggestions to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

Press `e` on grub boot screen and add `nouveau.modeset=0` on kernel boot parameter.
See if it fixes your video problem.